# Tkinter prevent disabled button from executing command

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, tkinter

I am having a little issue using the option command for a tkinter button.

In this example When the button is clicked executes a command, the command first disables the button, prints a message, then reads input and finally enables the button.

Code

```
import Tkinter as tk

def clicked():
    mybutton.config(state='disabled')
    print("clicked")
    raw_input()
    mybutton.config(state='active')

root = tk.Tk()

mybutton = tk.Button(root, text="Button", command = clicked)
mybutton.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

The issue I am having is that if I press the button several times, it executes the command multiple times, it waits until can read the input and then waits for input again.

I thought that disabling the button would prevent this from happening but seems is not.

How can I prevent the command from executing multiple times?

Note if it is relevant: I am using python 2.7.10 with PyDev Eclipse on Windows 7

Comment: Works as expected on my machine (Fedora 25, Python 2.7 and 3.5).

Comment: Can not reproduce. Even if I click the button as fast as I can, it gets deactivated (grayed out) before the second click is registered. (Python 2.7.12 on Xubuntu 16.03)

Comment: What happens if you only deactivate the button? Does that work? I.e., is the problem the deactivation, or that `raw_input` keeps the UI form refreshing?

Comment: @tobias_k without disabling-enabling it has the same behavior on my computer, the command gets executed multiple times, I am trying this with eclipse and PyDev, if it helps

Comment: @tobias_k No if I click once it gets executed only once, the problem is if the button is clicked multiple times before the input is readed. Without the `raw_input` works fine, the problem probably is related with the `raw_input` blocking until can read something.

Comment: @wallek876 That's what I wanted to know. :-) Now, the next question would be: Why are you reading `raw_input` in a UI program instead of using e.g. an Entry widget? Does the same happen with other long-running within the callback?

Comment: @tobias_k Reading input from console is just for reproducing the problem I am having in a simple manner for the question, in reality what the application does is write and read to a serial port, that has the same behavior in this case.